# AWS web app redirecting to Windows server page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an ASP.NET MVC application in visual studio and after that I publish it to AWS(Amazon web service) using the AWS toolkit for visual studio.
Everything worked fine and the upload was successful.

But when I click the generated environment URL for my web application, I am redirected to Windows server page instead of the `login.cshtml` page of my web app.

Here, is the URL to my web app. [mvcloginregistration](http://mvcloginregistration-test.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/). What I should do or what I did wrong.

Comment: It might be helpful if you post the messages generated in the Output box of the Visual Studio right after you deployed the app.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't save the output. Is there any way that I can that I can get it or should I redeploy the application?

Comment: Do you remember what application path you specified when you were deploying your app?

Comment: When I was publishing the application there was something that says 'App path:' and its default value was 'Default Web Site/', and I left like that. Is that   what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend you to deploy it again and check the log messages generated in the outbox just to make sure that everything went as expected. If this doesn't help try to connect to remote host using a RDC and check IIS Manager to see how it's configured.

Comment: Should I leave 'App path:' as it is?

Comment: Yes, leave it default.